# Querying with multiple where conditions and multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a `Policies` table.

---

- policyId
- status ("Pending" or "Issued")
- pendDate
- issueDate

---

Now I need get all pending `Policies` with a `pendDate` in the month of `October` AND all issued `Policies` with a `issueDate` in the month of October.

I'm using `postgreSQL 9.6`. These dates are nullable so I cant use a simple `AND`. I need only the `pending` and `issued` in that month so ORs dont work.

I solved with two queries but now more statuses are being added and I want to consolidate somehow. Possible?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly you can get it by using an OR condition in WHERE clause:

> ```
> create table Policies 
> (
>     policyId int,
>     status   varchar(100),
>     pendDate date,
>     issueDate date
> );
>
> insert into Policies values
> (1, 'Pending', '20171001', null),
> (2, 'Pending', '20171002', null),
> (3, 'Pending', '20171003', null),
> (4, 'Pending', '20171101', null),
> (5, 'Pending', '20171102', null),
> (6, 'Issue', null, '20171002'),
> (7, 'Issue', null, '20171003'),
> (8, 'Isuue', null, '20171101');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select policyId,
>        status,
>        pendDate,
>        issueDate
> from   Policies
> where  (status = 'Pending' and extract(year from pendDate) = 2017 and extract(month from pendDate) = 10)
> or     (status = 'Issue' and extract(year from issueDate) = 2017 and extract(month from issueDate) = 10)
> ```
>
> ```
> policyid | status  | penddate   | issuedate 
> -------: | :------ | :--------- | :---------
>        1 | Pending | 2017-10-01 | null      
>        2 | Pending | 2017-10-02 | null      
>        3 | Pending | 2017-10-03 | null      
>        6 | Issue   | null       | 2017-10-02
>        7 | Issue   | null       | 2017-10-03
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e9888285aff95617d15725a4808ae12d)*